# Having trouble with LFTP. Socket error when Connecting to Firezilla

Tags: bash, ftp, backup, lftp

I have a bash script that I am trying to run on my hostgator account.

```
cd $HOMEDIR
dir="$(date +'%a')"

# Upload backups (5 tries)
i=0
while [ $i -le 5 ]; do
  # We're running this more than once so it's advised to use -E to delete the
  # original file after successful transfer.
    lftp -d -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no; mrm backup-*.tar.gz; mput -c -E -O $dir backup-*.tar.gz;quit" -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASS -p $FTP_PORT $FTP_ADDR

    sleep 5
    ((i++))
done

# Delete backup before generating new b/c hostgator allows only one
rm backup-*.tar.gz

# Generate new full backup in Cpanel
PARAMS="dest=homedir&email=$EMAIL&submit=Generate%20Backup"
curl -u $CPANEL_USER:$CPANEL_PASS --data $PARAMS $CPANEL_HOST/frontend/x3/backup/dofullbackup.html
```

The above script leaves me with the error code below from the client side (hostgator):

```
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:                                                
<---  MDTM
<---  REST STREAM
<---  SIZE
<---  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
<---  MLSD
<---  AUTH SSL
<---  AUTH TLS
<---  PROT
<---  PBSZ
<---  UTF8
<---  CLNT
<---  MFMT
<---  EPSV
<---  EPRT
<--- 211 End
---> CLNT lftp/4.0.9
<--- 200 Don't care                                         
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
<--- 202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command.
---> USER emre**
<--- 331 Password required for emre**                   
---> PASS *******
<--- 230 Logged on                                                
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is current directory.                                    
---> TYPE I
<--- 200 Type set to I                                                
---> SIZE Fri/backup-6.17.2016_08-40-54_emre.tar.gz
<--- 550 File not found                                               
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (**,***,**,**,199,56)                  
---- Connecting data socket to (**.***.**.**) port 51000
**** Socket error (Connection refused) - reconnecting
---- Closing data socket
---- Closing control socket
```

The server system is firezilla running on windows 10.

```
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> Connected on port 2222, sending welcome message...
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> 220-FileZilla Server 0.9.57 beta
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> 220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> FEAT
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> 211-Features:
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  MDTM
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  REST STREAM
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  SIZE
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  MLSD
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  AUTH SSL
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  AUTH TLS
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  PROT
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  PBSZ
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  UTF8
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  CLNT
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  MFMT
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  EPSV
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)>  EPRT
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> 211 End
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> CLNT lftp/4.0.9
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> 200 Don't care
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> OPTS UTF8 ON
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> 202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command.
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> USER emre**
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> 331 Password required for emre**
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - (not logged in) (***.***.***.**)> PASS ********
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> 230 Logged on
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> PWD
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> PASV
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (76,100,88,71,199,56)
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> LIST
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> ABOR
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> 226 ABOR command successful
(000017)6/17/2016 19:01:11 PM - emre** (***.***.***.**)> disconnected.
```

I don't know what is going on? Can anyone send some light? I've been digging for hours now and cannot figure it out.

Comment: Did you notice this in your output? `---> SIZE Fri/backup-6.17.2016_08-40-54_emre.tar.gz ; <--- 550 File not found` . Somehow, you're not in the dir you think you are. Also I don't think `ftp` clients will process a  relative path as you seem to have, i.e. `Fri/backup..` , You'll need to `cd Fri` before issuing your `get` or `put` cmd. Good luck.                     `

Comment: I simplified the command to `lftp -d  -c "open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASS -p $FTP_PORT $FTP_ADDR set ftp:ssl-allow no; get -O test.txt ~/test.txt"
` and the server finds the file but then `**** Socket error (Connection refused) - reconnecting` What does this mean? The server does have FTP running which the error suggests otherwise.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice this before `---- Connecting data socket to (**.***.**.**) port 51000`. I'm no `ftp` expert, but I thought `ftp` used low port numbers. Given the error message, I would look closely at firewalls, routers, etc. Any place that can set rules for blocking network traffic. Good luck.

Comment: I know I changed the passive ports on the Firezilla server to 51000 because I do not know how to port forward a range of ports on my comcast modem. I can't find the option so I just made it a single port.